# C# Какая разница между типом исключения SystemException and Exception?

Tags: c#, исключения

В книге прочитал вот что:

> Учитывая, что тип System. SystemException не добавляет никакой дополнительной
> функциональности кроме набора специальных конструкторов, вас может интересовать,
> по какой причине он вообще существует. Попросту говоря, когда тип исключения является производным от System.SystemException, то есть возможность выяснить, что исключение сгенерировала исполняющая среда .NET, а не кодовая база выполняющегося
> приложения. Это довольно легко проверить, используя ключевое слово is:

```
        // Верно! NullReferenceException является SystemException.
        NullReferenceException myExc = new NullReferenceException();
        Console.WriteLine(myExp is SystemException); // True
```

НО

```
        myExp is Exception // true по логичным причинам
```

В чем тогда прикол этого всего? В книге ошибка? (книга Троелсен Э., Джепикс Ф. - Язык программирования C# 7 и платформы .NET и .NET Core - 2018)

Comment: Я так понял если создать производный класс от Exception то будет false на проверку is SystemException, если класс производный от SystemException то на проверку is SystemException будет true но и на Exception тоже. Тоже самое с экземплярами этих классов(объектами классов)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `SystemException` является базовым для исключений находящихся в пространстве имён `System` и на этом его задача заканчивается. [Можете убедиться](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.systemexception?view=net-7.0) в этом развернув классы которые наследуют это исключение, да и к слову сам msdn это говорит (как и слова в книге). Вам не нужно его трогать или генерировать этот тип исключения.

Однако, этот класс никакого отношения к исключениям `среды .NET` не относится, это некорректный перевод. Среда .NET (она же Execution Engine) раньше выбрасывала `ExecutionEngineException`, но это исключение устарело и не имеет никаких замен.

В книге скорее всего имелось, что исключение является одним из написаных маломягкими для C# и это можно проверить с помощью ключевого слова `is`.